# Messaging.sendEmail not sending emails for non-admin profile in sandbox

Tags: email, sandbox, singleemailmessage, invocable-method, send-email

In a partial sandbox I am calling `Messaging.sendEmail` through an `@InvocableMethod` through a Flow, and emails are not going out for a non-admin profile. There are **no errors** anywhere and even debugging `Messaging.SendEmailResult.isSuccess()` shows `true`. The arrangement works fine for an admin user.

I haven't tried with other profiles (or in other sandboxes or in Production) but I have verified that every occurrence of the word "email" throughout this one profile is met with a ticked box. Email deliverability is set to All Emails (should be obvious by now, but just being explicit) and the code is setting `templateId`, `whatId`, and `targetObjectId`. Dead basic. The profile in question has access to the template and the related records in `whatId` and `targetObjectId`.

FWIW I have also tried with `toAddresses` in the email with no luck.

Comment: Does the user have a valid email address on their user record in the sandbox (ex, not .invalid)?

Comment: and you checked the email logs to see if the email was sent/delivered?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves That was it!! Turned out the user hadn't verified the email change yet. The user's email was .invalid. Happy to mark your reply as best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a note at the bottom of this [help document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333417&type=1&mode=1) that clarifies there was a recent change (Summer '19) that is causing your issue

> Please note as of Summer Release 19', Users must have a verified email
> address and .invalid removed from the email address in order to send
> email alerts via Workflow, Process, Flows or Triggers.

I didn't find any note about it in Summer '19, but did see that [Spring '19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sandboxes_email_management.htm) introduced  the change to append `.invalid` to user email addresses in sandboxes which is most likely the source of the change.

Either way, if you change the user you're using/testing with to have a valid email address then the emails should send out.

*Just remember the user has to verify the email change through an email message they receive from Salesforce before the email actually changes*

Comment: I think I originally misinterpreted this answer, so I'm adding the clarification in case anyone else needs it. Change the email of the user YOUR ARE LOGGED IN AS, along with the recipient! That's because Salesforce will send the email from "noreply@salesforce.com on behalf of USER_WHO_TRIGGERED_EMAIL". Therefore your email needs to be a valid one.